# How to enable embedded tomcat logging

Tags: tomcat, logging

I m using embedded tomcat in my java application. below is my source code. however tomcat is not generating any log.

```
        embedded = new Embedded();
        embedded.setDebug(3);

        org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger embeddedFileLogger = new org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger();         
        embeddedFileLogger.setDirectory(tomcatHome+"/log");
        embeddedFileLogger.setPrefix("Embedded_log_");
        embeddedFileLogger.setSuffix(".txt");
        embeddedFileLogger.setTimestamp(true);
        embeddedFileLogger.setVerbosity(3);



        //embedded.setLogger(new SystemOutLogger());
        engine = embedded.createEngine();
        //engine.setLogger(embeddedFileLogger);
        embeddedFileLogger.setContainer(engine);
        engine.setDefaultHost("localhost");

        host = embedded.createHost("localhost", tomcatHome + "/webapps");
        //host.setLogger(embeddedFileLogger);
        engine.addChild(host);

        _context = embedded.createContext("", tomcatHome + "/webapps/ROOT");
        host.addChild(_context);

        embedded.addEngine(engine);

        CoyoteConnector connector = (CoyoteConnector)embedded.createConnector(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), port, false);               
                   embedded.addConnector(connector);
        embedded.setLogger(embeddedFileLogger);
        embedded.start();
```

Please let me know how can i enable embedded tomcat logging through code or tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me (Tomcat 9.0.38):

Add system property to point to my logging config:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/absolute/path/to/logging.properties
```

And the contents of `logging.properties` is:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE
```

Comment: It worked for me too thank you. I used FINEST for all logs

Comment: +1 for the `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` reference. Helped me point my integration tests to a custom `logging.properties` which redirects all Tomcat logging to SLF4J (and hence, to Logback).

Answer (score 4):

By default the embedded Tomcat uses the logging configuration provided by the JDK. If you haven't changed the configuration only a `ConsoleHandler` is configured. If you wanted to programmatically add a `FileHandler` you can add it to the root logger. Here's an example that writes to the file `catalina.out` by appending the messages on `INFO` level. This works for Tomcat 6.x and 7.x.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler("catalina.out", true);
fileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
fileHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
fileHandler.setEncoding("UTF-8");
logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
```

Comment: How can I do this for multiple embedded tomcat instances? I have an app that for each given war file create a tomcat instance and deploy it, but I don't know how to separate output for each instance. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Where you ever able to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked only partially. This requires adding one more line:

```
java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

I wanted to show **ALL** logs and make logging level configurable. Here is what worked for me:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Tuning log level
    if (args.length > 0) {
        Level level = Level.parse(args[0]);
        java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");
        logger.setLevel(level);
        Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();
        Handler handler;
        if (handlers.length == 1 && handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
            handler = handlers[0];
        } else {
            handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        }
        handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        handler.setLevel(level);
        handler.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        logger.addHandler(handler);
    }
    //... some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.15.jar in your classpath.

I used this code to load the logging.properties file and configure the logging externally using the normal java logging approach:

```
//Loads custom logging configuration located in a properties file named logging.properties
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("logging.properties")) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(inputStream);
    System.out.println("Custom logging configuraton loaded successfully");
} catch (Exception exception) {
    System.err.println ("Custom logging configuration don't found using default system logging configuration.");
}
```

For more details about configure the logging.properties use this pages:
[Tomcat logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html), [org.apache.juli.FileHandler](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html)

Also you can use the java.util.logging.FileHandler that is also compatible with the juli aproach an has another advanced configuration options: [java.util.logging.FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)

There is another jar for use log4j but for me this works fine.
Note: I used the tomcat embedded 8.0.15 but there are new versions now.

Answer (score 1):

I had just to figure out, how I can control the logging of the embedded Tomcat the same way the standalone version is doing it.

You will need the `tomcat-juli.jar`, because it has a custom `LogManager` in it. This `LogManager` has advantages, since it is capable of registering multiple `FileHandlers`. So it enables you to separate Logs per WebApp.

It is not enough to just include the `tomcat-juli.jar`, but you also need to **activate** its `LogManager`. This would be done through a JVM-Parameter:

`-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`

Now it is possible to register `FileHandlers` like shown in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)).

With an additional JVM-Parameter you can set the path to the `logging.properties`-File:

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/logs/logging.properties`

---

It is also possible to load the `.properties`-File programmatically, but then you need to set a `java.util.logging.config.class` with a JVM-Parameter, like above. In it's constructor you then must call `LogManager.readProperties(...)`. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration--) for more information.

Best regards